# corrupted sudoers file, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot, sudo

My `/etc/sudoers` file is somehow corrupted and all the users who have sudo privileges are unable to execute ANY command with sudo prefix to the command !

```
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/README near line 1
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I have tried almost all the solutions suggested in previous similar questions like

1. rebooted the system many times
2. Tried to modify the file `/etc/sudoers.d/README` but was unable to do so.
3. In recovery mode, mounted the file system with `rw` and tried to modify the mentioned file but was unsuccessful
4. `pkexec bash`..... still no use

The file line in `/etc/sudoers.d/README` is infact an empty line.

Can you please guide me !

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that all lines in the sudoers README have to be prefixed with a `#`.

I don't understand why README is being processed when you run sudo, but uncommented lines seem to break it. I only stumbled on this when an SD card in my raspberry pi started to fail and corrupted a number of files. This is despite the README file not being the only file in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu-based system (Mint) `/etc/sudoers.d/README` is all comments, like `# ...` there is no line that isn't a comment. And other files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` contain blank lines with no errors from sudo... is it possible your blank line contains some weird non-printable character? A hex editor should show anything weird in it.

And since the README file is all comments it shouldn't be necessary for sudo to work anyway, except for this comment in it:

```
# Note that there must be at least one file in the sudoers.d directory (this
# one will do), and all files in this directory should be mode 0440.
```

So as long as there's another file in that directory, you could try  moving your corrupt README file out of the dir and see if that helps.

And you should have been able to modify the file in a recovery mode in your attempt 3, I'm assuming you would have been given permission to modify any file, like booting from a live cd/dvd/usb, if you couldn't edit the file maybe the file &/or filesystem itself is corrupt, tried a `fsck` ?

And here's another well-liked (upvoted) guide on how to fix a corrupt sudoers file, if it doesn't work then I'd look into the fsck/corrupt filesystem possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, but it was my own actions that caused the problem. I was already using a file

```
/etc/sudoers.d/randy-sudoers
```

for my personal changes, as I was instructed to do.

I thought I was being smart to create a subdirectory off of my home, and create a randy-sudoers file there with me as owner and rw permissions. I could edit this file with mousepad (Xubuntu) as I pleased. Then I wrote a script to copy this file to /etc/sudoers.d.randy-sudoers and change the owner, group, and permissions as needed. This is discussed in this link and is marked as a good idea, but let me tell you, it is a BAD IDEA. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1352310&highlight=visudo+busy

The problem is that I made a mistake in the file. Once I copied it down to /etc/sudoers.d/randy-sudoers, all of a sudden my sudo commands didn't work anymore. It told me there was an error on line 20 of my file. I could modify that in my home subdirectory, but I couldn't use sudo to copy it down to /etc/sudoers again. All my attempts to use sudo were blocked, which I needed to do the copy.

Hunting around, I found what I needed to do was run this:

```
pkexec visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/randy-sudoers
```

This allowed me to bypass the sudo command and edit the file and remove/correct the offending line, and then save again. It prompted me to save as

```
/etc/sudoers.d/randy-sudoers.tmp
```

which I did. It then checked the validity of the tmp file and overwrote the original offending file. Whew! I was saved.